# Calling forms list values. Ribbon1.cs and Form1.cs

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, vsto, ribbon

I am developing a VSTO application. I have a button on Office **Ribbon1.cs**. and Form on **Form1.cs**. I call the form from the button creating a new form:

```
Form1 MallideVorm = new form Form1 (); // Create a form from Form1
MallideVorm.Show (); // Show the form
```

I have a list in my windows Form. I put strings in there:

```
foreach (Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File file in fileCol)
{
str = file.Name;

// File.AppendAllText (@ "C: \ install \ CSharp \ tulemus.txt", $ "File name: {str}" + Environment.NewLine); // for testing

foreach (form Form1 in System.Windows.Forms.Application.OpenForms)
{
if (frm.GetType () == typeof (Form1))
{
// RibbonDropDownItem ddItem1 = Globals.Factory.GetRibbonFactory (). CreateRibbonDropDownItem ();
//ddItem1.Label = $ "{str}";

Form1 frmTemp = (Form1) frm;
//ddList.Items.Add(ddItem1);
MallideVorm.addItemToListBoxFiles (file.Name);

}
}
}
```

All this is done with the **Ribbon1.cs**-s button. When I have a Form with a list, I would like to have in my **Form1.cs**: (to return the value that chosen)

```
private void FormFilesBox_SelectedIndexChanged (object sender, EventArgs e)
{string selectedFile = FormFilesBox.SelectedItem.ToString ();}
```

But that does not work. I think the problem is that I generate one **Form A** with the click of a button, but try to get values ​​from another **Form B**.
How can I define an action from Ribbon1.cs in Form1.cs or vice versa(`FormFilesBox_SelectedIndexChanged`). Or how can I refer to the one and same Form.

**The answer on Cindy suggestion:**
Thanks Cindy, but I don't know how to do that right. Word.interop has his own Globals [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.global)?view=word-pia
So if I will make some `public static class Globals {Form1 MallideVorm = new Form1(); }` Then I will have errors like :

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS0117  'Ribbon1.Globals' does not contain a definition for
>   'ThisAddIn'           470 Active Or definition for Factory...

Abount the form code: I have Windows form In the Form1.cs Design.
In Form1.cs is:

```
public void addItemToListBoxFolder(string item)
        {
            FormFolderBox.Items.Add(item);
        }

        public void addItemToListBoxFiles(string item)
        {
            FormFilesBox.Items.Add(item);
        }


        private void FormFilesBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //_______________________________________________________Sharepoindist faili alla laadimine ja sealt avamine________________________________________

            string selectedFile = FormFilesBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
            //Here is the question, how to take value from other Form.
          //In Ribbon1.cs it is declared as Form1 MallideVorm = new Form1();  //Creating form from Form1
     //   MallideVorm.Show(); 

            var destinationFolder = @"C:\install\CSharp\TestkaustDoc";
            ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext("https://Some/Some");
            //Configure the handler that will add the header.
            ctx.ExecutingWebRequest +=
            new EventHandler<WebRequestEventArgs>(ctx_MixedAuthRequest);
            //Set the Windows credentials.
            ctx.AuthenticationMode = ClientAuthenticationMode.Default;
            ctx.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            // Get a reference to the SharePoint site
            var web = ctx.Web;

            // Get a reference to the document library
            var list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Documents");


            // Get the list of files you want to export. I'm using a query
            // to find all files where the "Status" column is marked as "Approved"
            var camlQuery = new CamlQuery
            {
                ViewXml = @"<View>
                            <Query>
                                <Where>
                                <Eq>
                                    <FieldRef Name=""FileLeafRef"" />
                                    <Value Type=""Text"">" + $"{selectedFile}" + @"</Value>
                                </Eq>
                                </Where>
                                </Query>
                            </View>"
            };
            camlQuery.FolderServerRelativeUrl = "/Some/Shared Documents/Test";
            // Retrieve the items matching the query
            var items = list.GetItems(camlQuery);

            // Make sure to load the File in the context otherwise you won't go far
            ctx.Load(items, items2 => items2.IncludeWithDefaultProperties
                (item => item.DisplayName, item => item.File));

            // Execute the query and actually populate the results
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();

            // Iterate through every file returned and save them
            foreach (var item in items)
            {

                using (FileInformation fileInfo = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.OpenBinaryDirect(ctx, item.File.ServerRelativeUrl))
                {
                    // Combine destination folder with filename -- don't concatenate
                    // it's just wrong!
                    var filePath = Path.Combine(destinationFolder, item.File.Name);

                    // Erase existing files, cause that's how I roll
                    if (System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
                    {
                        System.IO.File.Delete(filePath);
                    }

                    // Create the file
                    using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.Create(filePath))
                    {
                        fileInfo.Stream.CopyTo(fileStream);
                    }
                }

            }
```

I solved it using:

```
foreach (Form1 frm in System.Windows.Forms.Application.OpenForms)
```

Like that:

In **Ribbon.cs** I am creating a new Form:

```
Form1 MallideVorm = new Form1();  //Creating form from Form1

          MallideVorm.Show(); // Showing form
```

Then using Application.OpenForms. (because the Form is one)

```
foreach (Form1 frm in System.Windows.Forms.Application.OpenForms)
                            {
                                if (frm.GetType() == typeof(Form1))
                                {


                                    Form1 frmTemp = (Form1)frm;

                                   frm.addItemToListBoxFiles(file.Name);
```

Then in **Form1.cs** the same way getting values from the ListBox.

```
foreach (Form1 frm in System.Windows.Forms.Application.OpenForms)

            {
                selectedFile =  FormFilesBox.SelectedItem.ToString();

            }
```

Comment: How about using the method to write the value to a class-level member ("global variable") in either the Form1 or the Ribbon class? You don't show the code for FormB, but you could pass the instance of Form1 to its constructor so that FormB would have access. And Ribbon.cs has an instance of FormA so could read that...

Comment: I dont know how to do it right. Word.interop has his own Globals.
I replied also as an answer to show a full code. In Ribbon1.cs I am loadin the lists and in Form1 I would like to retrieve them. Because the first trigger is Button click from the Ribbon.cs and the second trigger is the list click from the Form1.cs